# What is the difference between data-ng and ng?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have read that the difference between

```
ng-* and data-ng-*
```

in Angularjs is, that you get valid HTML if you use data-ng-*.
But why do I need that if I can declare the angular namespace in just one single line?

```
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app>
```

Or is it just for validating with an HTML Validator?

Excuse my stupidity, but I'm really confused about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just for validation of your HTML. No other purpose.